# Insufficient Input Validation Issue For Passed Model in Actionresult by Veracode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, veracode

This is my action

```
public ActionResult Account([Bind(Include = "UserDetail,PostedFileName,FileName,BrandList,ReplacementUsers,UserOrganizations,userViewModel,OrganizationList,BrandViewModel,UserModules,UserRoles,ModuleWiseHelpLinkCollection")]AccountViewModel accountViewModel)
```

After scanning with Veracode its showing insufficient input validation issue on this and almost all other actions where Models are passed.I can't figure out how to solve this as i tried to put Required on all properties but didn't worked out.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of reasearch what worked for me is using

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
ModelState.Clear();
```

in the begiining of action code.This Validates the models an thus solves the issue.
Got the reference from
[Technology-Specific Input Validation Problems](https://youtu.be/a15U7ePB24I)